# Debian Squeeze locale settings

Tags: debian, localization

I have a problem with a slightly customised Debian image that I'm trying to do some headless work on.  The problem is that the installed locales list has been reduced to this:

```
C
en_GB
en_GB.iso88591
en_GB.iso885915
en_GB.utf8
POSIX
```

However, when I log in as root (with an otherwise as-vanilla profile), I find this:

```
~# set | grep LC_
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

That's the only LC_ environment variable set, and presumably that means that it's being explicitly set somewhere (and given that /etc/default/locale only contains LANG=en_GB, I can't see any other alternative). However, I can't see where it is being set, and the fact that it's wrong is preventing, for example, postgresql-8.4 from installing.  I know I can do an

```
LC_CTYPE=en_GB apt-get install postgresql-8.4
```

to work around this, but I'd really like to understand where this setting comes from, and I *really* dislike the idea of installing an otherwise-unnecessary locale to make this go away.  So: where does this LC_CTYPE setting come from, and how do I make it go away?

Comment: check `/etc/environment`; it's where it used to be set. other options are `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `/etc/profile.d/something.sh`, but nothing should have automatically installed the variable in those files.

Comment: and you did run `locale-gen`, right?

Comment: `locale-gen` has been run, there's nothing in `/etc/environment` (empty file). I can't see anything relevant in `/etc/bash.bashrc`, and the only thing in `/etc/profile.d` is `bash_completion.sh` which, from an eyeball scan and a `grep LC_`, looks irrelevant.

Comment: try running `bash --noprofile --norc`. if this doesn't pick up the `LC_CTYPE`, your issue must be in one of those startup files

Comment: It's not being set when I run `bash --login` *or* `bash --noprofile --norc`. I can run `LC_CTYPE=FOO bash <whatever>` and LC_CTYPE is set to FOO inside the new shell in both cases.

Comment: In that case you should check `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`. If any of those files that exist source (`. /usr/local/custom.sh` or `source /usr/local/custom.sh`) other files, check them too. Your `LC_CTYPE` is probably being set in one of them.

Comment: None of those turned out to be the problem, it was a little more subtle than that. See below for what I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, I have found the problem, and it's nothing to do with Bash.

The problem is that sshd_config has the following entry:

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

This allows my local environment variables named LC_whatever (including LC_CTYPE, the problematic one) to override remote settings so, when I connected, the ssh process set its environment variables accordingly, and the bash process dutifully inherited them. Nowhere in this process is there a check that the LC_CTYPE setting is valid on the far side of the SSH connection.

My temporary fix is to specify a known good LC_CTYPE in the specific command I run on the far side. I don't know what the "correct" solution to this is.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the missing locales:

```
apt-get install debconf
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Choose the locales you would like to install.

Comment: That's not an ideal solution: the image I was working on is a cut-down image for VM deployment. The reason locales were cut out was for space reasons, and even if I wanted to install locales I'd have to do it for every single VM I connected to.

Comment: You wanted the "correct" solution...

Comment: Adding more packages to a misconfigured system is rarely "correct", in any sense.

Comment: If you don't want locales, then get rid of all of them and just use the `C` locale. Then you can forget about the whole thing. :)