# How to fix locale settings in Debian squeeze

Tags: localization, debian-squeeze

I occasionally get locale errors and I've tried to run dpkg-reconfigure locales to fix the problem. Here's the output:

```
:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "C"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "C"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

I looked for /usr/bin/locale but it doesn't exist on my system. Do I need to create it? What do I put in there?

Also I found a [related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/292698/debian-squeeze-locale-settings) that says the cause of his problem was in the sshd_config file. The file had the following entry:

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

I'm mainly concerned that it may cause problems for my VPS, otherwise if it's nothing major I'll be happy to ignore the problem. What should I do? thanks!

Comment: This same problem (LC_CTYPE=UTF-8, which is wrong) can happen when you login over ssh from a Mac to a linux box, and your terminal automatically sets environment variables. There's a checkbox for that. Uncheck it, and you're good to go. In iTerm it's in the profile->Terminal Tab.

Comment: There seem to be a bug with some debian based distribution (including ubuntu).  Using fr_FR.UTF-8 was giving problems (and the locale existed).  Doing a `locale-gen fr` would build all fr locales (fr_BE, fr_CH etc...) solves the issue. Perhaps try `locale-gen en`

Answer (score 18):

first:

```
sudo apt-get purge locales
```

then:

```
sudo aptitude install locales
```

and the famous:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

This rids the system of locales, then re-installs locales and downgrades libc6 from 2.19 to 2.13 which is the issue. Then configures locales again.

Comment: I have the exact the same problem. So by this answer and including the jessie repositories, I could install `locales` without downgrade `libc6`.

Comment: this didn't help

Answer (score 17):

If this happens when SSHing to your box, but not on console, try reconfiguring your **ssh client** (on your local machine). On Mac OS X for example edit /private/etc/ssh_config and comment out

```
# SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

Thanks to the post of bredman on the [Rasberry Pi Bulletin Board](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=11870).

Comment: This file now: /private/etc/ssh/ssh_config

Comment: This works assuming that the remote client does not have the locale issue.

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem for a long time and all the usual advice about dpkg-reconfigure locales, locale-gen, etc didn't help. So I played around a little bit with the environment variables, and what I found was that the system was borking on the `LC_CTYPE` environment variable! `UTF-8` is not a valid value for it. Setting it to `en_US.UTF-8` fixed it.

To make the change permanent, I ran

```
update-locale LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

which writes to `/etc/default/locale`.  And then reboot the system for it to take effect completely.

Comment: Unfortunately, this yields `perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
 LANGUAGE = (unset),
 LC_ALL = (unset),
 LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
 LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
*** update-locale: Error: invalid locale settings:  LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 3):

If you disabled PAM authentication for ssh in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (`UsePAM no`) the responsible configuration in `/etc/pam.d/login` isn't effective:

`session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale`

The result: `/etc/default/locale` seems to have no effect.

So you have to configure your client to send the LANG vars or export the env vars in the profile scripts like `~/.profile`, `~/bashrc` etc.

More: http://wiki.debian.org/Locale#Standard

Comment: I love you and I am forever grateful

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this before on older Debian installs, and while annoying, I've never seen it cause a problem.

If

```
  /usr/bin/locale
```

is missing, try (as root):

```
  apt-get install libc-bin
```

that should install libc-bin, providing /usr/bin/locale.

That AcceptEnv line in your sshd_config is pretty standard, and shouldn't be the the cause of your problem here.

Comment: libc-bin was already installed, so I updated it and tried running `dpkg-reconfigure locales` again. No joy :(

Comment: Does /usr/bin/locale exist now?  If so, what is the output of:
`locale -a`
and what is in
`/etc/default/locale`
?

Comment: The contents of `/etc/default/locale' :

    #  File generated by update-locale
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: `locale -a` gives me:

    locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
    C
    en_US.utf8
    POSIX

Comment: apt was claiming that libc-bin was installed, but at least one file was missing (/usr/bin/locale), and reinstalling libc-bin seems to have fixed that. Can you try `apt-get install --reinstall locales`? Then, for good measure, try `locale-gen`, which will regenerate any locales that are uncommented in `/etc/locale.gen` (you should have a line like `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8`). After this, see if `locale -a` works.

Comment: still didn't work :( `locale -a` returns the same output as above. Appreciate your time Chad, I might contact my host's support team for this.

Answer (score 2):

Did the following, as Manoj, but added it to #~/.bashrc:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.utf8
```

Answer (score 2):

Mac connecting to a fresh Debian 10 install. None of the answers googled all over Stack Exchange helped. Here's what did (and was straightforward and reliable too):

```
sed -i "s/^AcceptEnv/#AcceptEnv/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Run this on your Debian box and it will stop the connecting mac terminal from messing up the server locales ([more info](https://blog.remibergsma.com/2012/07/10/setting-locales-correctly-on-mac-osx-terminal-application/)).

As a bonus, that may even [improve security](https://serverfault.com/questions/427522/why-is-acceptenv-considered-insecure) of the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the errors while ssh'ing to a remote system, and don't want to modify the remote system (by changing the sshd_config, for instance), you can do the following on your local system (assuming bash)

```
export LC_ALL=en_US
export LANGUAGE=en_US
```

and then `ssh user@remote`

Answer (score 1):

On my fresh Debian installation (minimal) locales was completely missing. Installing it (`aptitude install locales`) and running `locale-gen` did the trick though. So guys, do as Chad Feller mentioned but check for having the package `locales` installed first.

Answer (score 1):

I was using German VPS and couldn't change locale because there was no English language pack installed.

After installing I could finally change locale

```
aptitude install language-pack-en
```

Answer (score 1):

on Debian systems this will resolve your problem:

`apt-get install locales-all`

on Ubuntu systems install specific language pack, for example:

`apt-get install language-pack-en`

`locale-gen en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem which was very bothering and spamming the terminal window.
Main issue, that my client is MacOS box. See below.

As I have seen, all the solutions are *locales* package and settings related, but the root cause is SSH!

Remote Linux server, fresh installed Debian Buster complains:

```
locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I connect to remote systems from MacOS Terminal, which has setting:

```
uname -a
Darwin mac-pro.lan 19.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Tue Nov 10 00:10:30 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.141.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

set | grep LC_
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
```

Here it is! Local, non Linux standard language setting is passed to remote Linux server.

On remote Linux server edit the **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** and comment out the LC_ variable passthrough:

```
# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
#AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

Restart the ssh daemon:

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

logout from remote ssh, login again, and vualia:

```
locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Not to bother with every single server, just fix your (MacOS client) side:

```
echo "export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8">>~/.bash_profile
```

if you use zsh use **~/.zprofile** instead.

This way, you setup more Linux compatible language setting, and no more remote Linux server complains!

Comment: In /etc/ssh/sshd_config Monterey there is no line with `#AcceptEnv LANG LC_*`

Comment: Made edits to be very clear, that sshd_config file is on remote Linux server. Most reliable solution is to set local profile though.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use grep command to search for specific locales.

```
## For example, search for English India ##
grep en_IN /etc/locale.gen
 
## Search for English US ##
grep en_US /etc/locale.gen
 
## Search for Japanese ##
grep ja_JP /etc/locale.gen
```

then,

```
felipe@SDF-1:~$ tail -f /etc/locale.gen
# zh_HK BIG5-HKSCS
# zh_HK.UTF-8 UTF-8
# zh_SG GB2312
# zh_SG.GBK GBK
# zh_SG.UTF-8 UTF-8
# zh_TW BIG5
# zh_TW.EUC-TW EUC-TW
# zh_TW.UTF-8 UTF-8
# zu_ZA ISO-8859-1
# zu_ZA.UTF-8 UTF-8

^C
felipe@SDF-1:~$ locale

LANG=en_US.UTF-8

LANGUAGE=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8

felipe@SDF-1:~$
```

also, helped me this:

```
felipe@SDF-1:~$ sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
Generation complete.
felipe@SDF-1:~$ sudo localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
felipe@SDF-1:~$ sudo export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
sudo: export: command not found
felipe@SDF-1:~$  sudo export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
sudo: export: command not found
felipe@SDF-1:~$ export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
felipe@SDF-1:~$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
felipe@SDF-1:~$ export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory
felipe@SDF-1:~$ sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
Generation complete.
felipe@SDF-1:~$ export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
felipe@SDF-1:~$ export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
felipe@SDF-1:~$ 
felipe@SDF-1:~$ 
felipe@SDF-1:~$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
felipe@SDF-1:~$
```

I just got to something else:

I have to add the fact that I had the same problems, still. But then I tried this, and it got fixed:

Added it to

```
#~/.bashrc:

export LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.utf8
```

and then, restarted SSH demon:

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

Comment: And what does this Duplicate Answer solve? export sets that only for one times, and after logout its lost

Comment: I don't know, but at some point I messed up the whole thing LOL, and I had to do the second option, man.

Comment: I come out with something else ... it's at the bottom ...