# How configure environment variable with AcceptEnv

Tags: linux, ssh, environment-variables

In /etc/ssh/sshd_config, there is an option called AcceptEnv that allows the ssh client to send environment variables. I need to be able to send a large number of environment variables,
how can i do this?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/427522/why-is-acceptenv-considered-insecure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify multiple environment variables on one line with `AcceptEnv`, and you can even give the option multiple times if you want.

For example:

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
```

The man page also stated this:

> Multiple environment variables may be separated by whitespace or spread across multiple AcceptEnv directives.

Comment: Since `AcceptEnv` arguments only add to the list of accepted variable names, I'm wondering if there's a way to make it reset (i.e. empty) that list?